# How to use dd to dump an image to unallocated space

Tags: linux, partition, dd

I have a bin file (`chromiumos_image.bin`) which contains some (around 12) partitions, which I need to dump into the unallocated space between 2 other partitions. The partition table is this:
[My partition table, as seen in gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUR2Y.png)
I want to dump my `chromiumos_image.bin` file into that unallocated 59.76GB space. How can I make dd understand that I want the unallocated space to be dd'ed?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really how dd works. The partition table is on the raw disk and to restore those 12 partitions you will end up overwriting your current partition table.

You're going to have to dd the .bin to a raw disk somewhere and then create a new .bin for each individual partition.

You can then setup the partitions as needed in the allocated space and dd each partition.

Comment: I have a problem, actually chromium OS has a ridiculous file system - with more than 12 little partitions, and dividing the bin file would be too hard to do, as I can't mount it as /dev/loop1:
`sudo mount chromiumos_image.bin /media/alex/chromiumos/ \n
NTFS signature is missing. \n
Failed to mount '/dev/loop1': Invalid argument \n
The device '/dev/loop1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
`
. Btw does gparted have a hidden tool somewhere that does that job?

Comment: @user258456 Try running a partition manager on `/dev/loop1`.  This will allow you to find the offsets to the partitions inside the file.  Mount the partitions using the offsets specified by the partition table.

Comment: I don't get that actually... :/